# Sci-fi story: Two men discover ability to see/sense telepathic aliens/monsters on Earth by inserting metal into brain

Tags: story-identification, aliens, telepathy, ancient-races

What is the name of this book?

The story starts with a worker who accidentally gets a pick-axe or metal spike lodged into his head and starts seeing or sensing strange things. A scientist/doctor investigates and determines that the metal inserted into his brain enables extra-sensory perception. The scientist/doctor (and a friend?) decide to intentionally insert a piece of metal into their own brains to replicate the effect. They become aware of massive and ancient telepathic alien/monster beings on Earth who notice them too and now they're in trouble and have to warn the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[The Philosopher's Stone](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8900)** by Colin Wilson

Howard Lester and Henry Littleway are friends who accidentally discover that putting a tiny shard of special medal into their foreheads allows one to focus his mind. They develop ESP in several varieties, including the power to see historical events.

But then they discover the existence of powerful beings from other dimensions who do not want to be found out.